# Lenovo service partition destroyed

Tags: lenovo-laptop

Good day. My lenovo ideapad 110 fell a small distance and from there it wont start up. It only said: lenovo service partition destroyed.
I then googled how to fix it, and I tried getting into the boot menu using: By pressing F8, and long pressing it.
And by pressing shift and the power button. 
It then only said Checking media[fail]
I then changed the boot mode (finally figured out how to get to the boot menu).
From UEFi to LEGACY SUPPORT. The laptop restarted and asked to insert a boot disk. I then changed the boot mode twice from UEFI to LEGACY SUPPORT. Its currently on legacy support, (it was on uefi before i changed anything, but is now on legacy support) now it only makes a black screen. How can I fix it. Please help me

Comment: You will probably have to take the disk somewhere to have the data recovered - which may or may not be possible, and may or may not be expensive - and then replace the disk and do a fresh install from the Lenovo Recovery Disk (that you made when you first got the computer and were running through the startup configuration process).

Comment: The first thing is set it back to UEFI, that how the OS was installed, that's how any troubleshooting and repair should proceed from.

Comment: **Do not** continue trying to use that drive (in write mode) if you hope to recover anything. Make a bootable USB drive, boot from that and copy as much of the internal disk as possible before trying any other repair.

Answer (score 0):

Is it an HD or SSD?

Potentially the SATA cable could be slightly loose, but if it's an HD, it may have died in the fall, especially if the computer was powered on at the time.

If you're not comfortable with stripping out the drive & testing on another computer, then a service technician should be your next port of call.